# Hora no se actualiza

Tags: java

Tengo una clase en la que quiero obtener la hora actual del pc pero esta no se actualiza, siempre es la misma hora, ¿alguna solucion?.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Hora extends Thread{

Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
int hora, minutos, segundos;   

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        setHora();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Hora.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}      

 public void setHora() {
    String h;
    hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    segundos = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    h = hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;
    System.out.println(h);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Saludos, Steven.

Lo que pasa es que estás instanciando tu `Calendar` una sola vez, y por defecto, al momento de instanciarse, sino le asignas ninguna fecha, él tomará la fecha por defecto del sistema al momento de su instanciación:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Es decir, al momento de instanciar tu clase `Hora`, automáticamente tu clase `Calendar` tomará la fecha y hora actual de tu sistema, entonces al momento de llamar a tu método `setHora`, tomará esa fecha y hora anterior.

Si lo que deseas es obtener la fecha y hora actual de tu sistema, entonces instancia un nuevo `Calendar` en tu método `setHora` o bien, asígnale a tu `Calendar`, la fecha y hora actualizadas:

```
public void setHora() {
    c.setTime(new java.util.Date()); // coloqué toda la clase para que sepas a cual clase Date me refiero

    String h;
    hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    segundos = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    h = hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;
    System.out.println(h);
}
```

De esa manera, le asignarás a tu `Calendar` la fecha y hora actual, que obtenemos gracias a la clase `Date`, otra manera, como te indiqué, es instanciar nuevamente tu `Calendar`:

```
public void setHora() {
    c = new GregorianCalendar();

    String h;
    hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    segundos = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    h = hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;
    System.out.println(h);
}
```

Acá te adjunto el link de la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#Calendar()) para la clase `Calendar`.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

- Declaras una variable del tipo `Date` en tu método, al cual he llamado `getHora`, para mantener un estándar de convención de nombres.
- Para simplificar, daremos formato con `SimpleDateFormat`. No hay por qué usar tres variables para luego concatenarlas...

El método quedaría así:

```
public void getHora() {
    Date fechaHoy = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String horaActual=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(fechaHoy);
    System.out.println(horaActual);    
}
```

- En la clase principal, creas un `Timer` desde el cual se llame a `getHora` cada un segundo. No lo puedo probar ahora mismo, pero creo haber leído que es mejor usar `Timer` que usar un `Thread`.

Algo así:

```
   Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
            getHora();
         // myTextField.setText(hora retornada eventualmente); 
        }
    }, 0L, 1000L);
```

Si quisieras mostrar la información en un `TextField` por ejemplo, puedes hacer que `getHora()` devuelva un `String` con el dato ya formateado y cambiar el valor del elemento dentro del `Timer`.